# Unable to set up HDFS interface with PyArrow

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, pyarrow

I am trying to access the HDFS directory using pyarrow as follows.

1. Install Hadoop and Spark
2. Locate libhdfs.so

> /usr/local/hadoop-3.3.5/lib/native/libhdfs.so

3. Create Home Directories

> ```
> import os
> os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"   # default is changed
> os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] = "/usr/local/hadoop-3.3.5/"
> os.environ['ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR'] = '/usr/local/hadoop-3.3.5/lib/native/'
> new_path = current_path+':/usr/local/hadoop-3.3.5/bin/'
> os.environ["PATH"] = new_path
> ```

4. Define Hive ( or Spark SQL databases)

> ```
> spark.sql("show databases").show()
>
> +---------+
> |namespace|
> +---------+
> |  default|
> +---------+
> ```

5. Create new database, load tables

> ```
> sql_create_database = "create database if not exists analytics location '/content/spark-warehouse/'"
> result_create_db = spark.sql(sql_create_database)
> sql_create_table = """
> create table if not exists analytics.pandas_spark_hive
> using parquet
> as select to_timestamp(date) as date_parsed, *
> from air_quality_sdf
> """
> result_create_table = spark.sql(sql_create_table)
> ```

6. Locate parquet files with new table data

> ```
> !ls /content/spark-warehouse/pandas_spark_hive
> part-00000-670c5cc7-8241-4744-9fbc-eddb640ccc19-c000.snappy.parquet 
> _SUCCESS
> part-00001-670c5cc7-8241-4744-9fbc-eddb640ccc19-c000.snappy.parquet
> ```

7. Create HDFS interface

> ```
> import pyarrow as pa
> hdfs_interface = pa.hdfs.connect(host='localhost', port=50010)
> <ipython-input-71-efc100d06888>:6: FutureWarning: pyarrow.hdfs.connect is deprecated as 
> of 2.0.0, please use pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem instead.
> hdfs_interface = pa.hdfs.connect(host='localhost', port=50010)
> ```

9. Now when I try to connect, I get an error

> ```
> hdfs_interface.ls('/content/spark-warehouse/')
> OSError: [Errno 255] HDFS list directory failed. Detail: [errno 255] Unknown error 255
> ```

I have tried different ports and file paths but each time I am getting the same error.
Would be grateful for any help

Comment: If you want to replicate the problem, the notebook is available at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lZoguVZ9n-REyvJQxH3GRTiAp6V-Hkf3?usp=sharing